# XMLHttpRequest - Send a string instead of a number

Tags: html, http, request

I'm using this webpage, found here: https://wp.josh.com/2014/05/01/a-platform-for-casual-encounters/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'>
<title>Toggle</title>
</head>
<body><center>
<script>
function send(s) {
    r=new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open('GET','/cgi-bin/control.cgi?COMMAND='+s+'&'+(new Date()).getTime(),false);
    r.send(null);
 }
</script>
<H1>Toggle</H1>
<button onclick='send(1);'>On</button>
<button onclick='send(0);'>Off</button>``
</center></body>
```

It works perfectly, i can receive the numbers on my terminal. Now i'm trying to send a string instead of "0" or "1". I tried to use  `<button onclick='send(ON);'>On</button>` but i can only receive the first letter. 
I think the problem is the script, how can i edit it to accept strings? I'm new to HTML, i need some support. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "i can only receive the first letter"? When you call `send(ON)`, `ON` is a variable which does not point to anything, which makes `undefined`. To pass string, you should wrap it with `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<button onclick="send('ON');">On</button>
```